# What does "decomposition" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "decomposition" mean? Is it short for "biologocal decomposition"? Does it have to be done by microorganisms? Can I use it in relation to glass that does not decompose in the biological sense? It does break down but doesn't rot. The authors of [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212609016301157) paper are apparently of the opinion that "decomposition" is not how I can describe what happens to glass after it is discarded.

> Once the glass becomes a waste it is disposed as landfills, which is unsustainable as this **does not decompose** in the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common meaning of 'decomposition' is exactly as you stated - the process by which organic material breaks down by biodegradation.

However, the word is the antonym of 'compose', which means to create by bringing components together, and the [various definitions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/decompose) of 'decompose' in dictionaries suggest that there is some variation in the processes it refers to. It always means some kind of 'natural' decay or degradation - it would not refer to manual, deliberate deconstruction of something.

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biodegradation) for biodegradation suggests that glass *does* decompose, just incredibly slowly - 1 million years in a terrestrial environment.

Comment: So do you think I can use it with "glass"?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Glass does biodegrade - just very slowly. A quick Google suggests that a glass bottle would take 1 million years to decompose on terrain, possibly never if submerged in water. So you could say it takes that long (or not) to decompose. I would say that in most cases, decompose and biodegrade would be interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

decomposition: to rot or decay, break into constituent parts (Merriam Webster)

Here is a New Year's Fix for you. "glass breaks down" but it does not decompose organically. The authors are right. ***decomposition** is for organic materials in environmental contexts*. Although, you can say glass decomposes, it does not decompose **biologically**.

"Once glass becomes waste, it is disposed of [or discarded] in landfills, which is unsustainable as it is not **biodegradable**" even though eventually it will decompose or break down into its constituent parts.

Happy New Year. [no "the" and no "a"; Both are non-countable nouns here.]

Glass is not biodegradable.

[Is Glass biodegradable](https://ecofreek.com/biodegradable/is-glass-biodegradable/)

> If it’s not Biodegradable, then how long does it take to
> **decompose**? Will it be in our lifetime?

So, yes, glass will eventually **break down or decompose** but it is not subject to biodegradable decomposition.

Comment: Could you make your answer a bit more consistent? "decomposition is for organic materials in environmental contexts", "glass will eventually break down or decompose"

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev or is used in English to mean a synonym: glass will eventually break down=glass will eventually decompose.  Decomposition USUALLY refers to biodegradable  things in an environmental context. So, my rewrite uses biodegradable to clarify your sentence. My answer is very, very clear and very consistent, too.